# error: too few arguments to function 'int Solution(std::vector<int>, int)'

Tags: c++, vector

i am using hackerrank , but whdn i started moving to the leetcode i stuck there and getting problem , please help me to get out of these, here is the problem statement below
name of the problem is two sum and below the problem statement is :

Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:

Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1]

i have already tried it . Here my code is :

```
int Solution(vector<int> nums,int target){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
        for(j=0;j<nums.size();j++){
            if(nums[i]+nums[j]==target && i!=j){
                cout<<i<<" "<<j;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but its gives errors , the site is not user friendly as hackerrank . Hackerrank provides the given input as well as output to show , but in leetcode i can't understand to use it . Please help me to get out of it .

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/

Comment: Arguments aren’t parameters, the error refers to calling code.

Comment: here is the link for the above problem ....plzzz help me to explain how can i write code in leetcode for submission of the question ........

Comment: in c++ plzzzzzz

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related to your problem, but the supplied signature takes a `vector<int>& nums`, whereas yours only takes a `vector<int> nums` (copy pass instead of pass by reference).

Comment: Without [mcve] it's not possible to help. Don't link to necessary information. Insert all necessary information into your question.

Comment: i can't understand the the process of writing code in leetcode ..... . can anyone help me to understand that is it needed the main() or only the solution function . is header files are also not required here ???

Comment: Seriously ? You only have to fill the gap in the provided window. All is provided, there's nothing to provide except what you have already written. The definition of the function is already setup. What do you not understand ?

Comment: I think you have to provide a class `Solution` with a method `twoSum`.

Comment: get out of it? simple, close the site an turn to some serious coding. Dont get trapped into beleving online coding would be a good tool to learn the language

Comment: Compile Error
solution.cpp: In member function __helper__
Line 18: Char 34: error: too few arguments to function 'int Solution(std::vector<int>, int)'

Comment: You should not create a function `Solution`. You need a class `Solution` with a method `twoSum`

Comment: but i didn;t understand the the function definition part . given below ...plzz seee and help

Comment: vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {     }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not create a function `Solution`. You need a class `Solution` with a method `twoSum`

```
class Solution {
    std::vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums,int target){
       // your solution
       // return indices
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks sir but in the problem statement, it was given that return the indices     , so can i simply print the indices ?

Comment: @shubhamgoswami no, you have to return them in a vector, not to print them.

Comment: thanks everyone for help ..... more thanks to @ThomasSabik         i have submitted my code and now i understand it very well      :

Comment: class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int i,j,temp;
        vector<int> v;
        for(i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
            for(j=0;j<nums.size();j++){
                if((nums[i]+ nums[j])==target && i!=j){
                    temp=i;
                    v.push_back(temp);
                    temp=j;
                    v.push_back(temp);
                    break;
                }
            }if(v.size()==2){break;}
        }
        return v;
    }
};